# How to host multiple flask applications in a single docker container?

Tags: api, docker, flask, docker-image

In project I have two flask applications, first api is called on batch of documents and classifies them into predicted classes and it maintains the status of all batches in a json file. The work of second api is to tell the status of a particular batch by which it is hit by reading the status file. Now we can not execute the applications on different containers as both have dependency of a file. The status telling api tells the live status of a batch so we also cannot wait for the processing api to finish it's atsk first and then export the status file to be used by second api. How should I approach this challenge, any leads would be of great help.

### Initially I was trying these lines in the docker file:

CMD ["python3", "./pollingAPI.py"] CMD ["python3", "./m_api.py"]

### I also tried nohup in the command but no results:

RUN nohup python3 pollingAPI.py & sleep 5 CMD ["python3", "./m_api.py"]

### Using screen also couldn't work:

RUN nohup python3 pollingAPI.py & sleep 5 && screen -S myScreen CMD ["python3", "./m_api.py"]

Comment: You could consider using a Docker volume shared between two containers to hold the file you need for synchronization.  Better still would be to design a different synchronization system that doesn’t need a file (and a shared filesystem).  This will be much easier if you only try to run one process in a container.

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze is it possible to map a folder on our local system to the docker container so that I can map the same folder to another container, in this way it would be possible for both the containers to read the same file. And as per your recommendation I also tried to find a way to eliminate the dependency but it's quite impossible to remove this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

So Docker best practices states that each container should only have one major application running in a container. The reason being that you want your application to run on PID 1 and accept any and all stop commands by itself. Your best case would always be to run two separate containers, each running one application.

That being said, this document clear outlines the three major options you have to run multiple services in the container. I would suggest using supervisord, but all of them are valid.

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/